# Google Sheets - Query Multiple Sheets That Have Different Structure

Tags: arrays, sum, google-sheets-formula, vlookup, google-query-language

Seeking assistance regarding how to structure a query that will be processing data from multiple sheets (ie tabs), however both sheets have different data structure.

The first query (below) queries a tab that contains all of my expenses itemised. This sums them by month.
=query(Expense_Data, "SELECT C, SUM(Q) where T Matches 'Expense' GROUP BY C ORDER BY C desc limit 3 label SUM(Q) 'Expenses'",1)

Example Data Output Below

| Date | Expenses |
| --- | --- |
| 01/01/2021 | -$1000 |
| 01/02/2021 | -$1500 |
| 01/03/2021 | -$1000 |

What I am seeking is to query another sheet which contains data (located in column G) that I wish to return based upon the date returned from the first query (located in column A), which I will then calculate the difference between. My issue is associating the 2 data sets together. Any support would be greatly appreciated!

| Date | Expenses | Budget | Difference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2021 | -$1000 | -$2000 | -$XXXX |
| 01/02/2021 | -$1500 | -$1500 | -$XXXX |
| 01/03/2021 | -$1000 | -$1500 | -$XXXX |

Comment: share a copy/sample of your sheet with example of desired result

Comment: Can do. Here is a sample: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eJerVMig0CYzFgqmbZz1DB4LYwh5zXmtrdvTJEYc6ts/edit#gid=608657316

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY(Expense_Input, 
 "select C,sum(Q) 
  where T matches 'Expense' 
  group by C 
  order by C desc 
  limit 3 
  label sum(Q) 'Expenses', C'Month' 
  format C'mmmm yyyy'", 1)
```

then:

```
={"Budget"; ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(TO_TEXT(A13:A), 
 {'Expense Lookup (Monthly)'!C:C&" "&'Expense Lookup (Monthly)'!D:D, 
 SUBSTITUTE('Expense Lookup (Monthly)'!G:G, "$", )*1}, 2, 0)))}
```

and:

```
={"Difference"; INDEX(IF(A13:A="",,C13:C-B13:B))}
```

[image]

---

### update

in one go:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({QUERY(Expense_Input, 
 "select C,sum(Q) 
  where T matches 'Expense' 
  group by C 
  order by C desc 
  limit 3 
  format C 'mmmm yyyy'", 1), IFNA(VLOOKUP(TEXT(INDEX(QUERY(Expense_Input, 
 "select C,sum(Q) 
  where T matches 'Expense' 
  group by C 
  order by C desc 
  limit 3",1),,1), "mmmm yyyy"), 
 {'Expense Lookup (Monthly)'!C:C&" "&'Expense Lookup (Monthly)'!D:D, 
 SUBSTITUTE('Expense Lookup (Monthly)'!G:G, "$", )*1}, 2, 0))}, 
 "select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col3-Col2 
  label Col1'Month',Col2'Expenses',Col3'Budget',Col3-Col2'Difference'"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way that this can be achieved within the same query? As I thought we could achieve the 'Difference' via the arthimetic function ie (Col2-Col3)?

Comment: Thankyou it appears to work. I'm curious to understand how this vlookup/query combination works. Are there any references you can share with me to understand it in more detail? :) Thanks again

Comment: @raym01 vlookup looks up for match in first column of given range and it can return any column from given range. in your case we create virtual table/array with array brackets {} and we put there next to each other these formulae: we run the first query within one sheet. next to it we run the same query but we use only first column of the outputed query table as the basis for looking up things in the second sheet and thats basically it